# Apache error 0xc000007b

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, apache-2.4

I am setting up Apache 2.4 on 64-bit Windows Server 2008 R2. I downloaded the 32-bit zip from Apache Lounge and unzipped, also installed VC10 SP1.

Then, when I tried to run httpd.exe, I got an error:
The application failed to initialize properly(0xc000007b)

The same thing worked on my 64-bit Win7.

Any insights?

---

### EDIT

Ran Depency Walker on httpd.exe. Missing dependencies are:

- IESHIMS.DLL
- MF.DLL
- MFPLAT.DLL
- MFREADWRITE.DLL
- WLANAPI.DLL

**IESHIMS.DLL**: This is also missing in my Win7 httpd. Don't think is the problem.
**WLANAPI.DLL**: Go to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Server Manager > Features (left panel) > Add Feature > check Wireless LAN Services to enable it. After that, wlanapi.dll is in the system32 folder.
**The rest**: These are related to "Media Foundation", but I don't know how to install/enable.
(edit: Some say installing "Desktop Experience" will include Media Foundation, will test)

---

### EDIT2

Apache 2.2 from apache.org is also missing those dlls but runs perfectly fine on the server!!

So, it's not a dependency problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, found a workaround.

Downloaded the VC9 version instead of the VC10 one and it runs without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Though you are not building your own application, the error (and solution) still apply.

[**Stack Overflow** - The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492037/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b)

**Edit:**

Additionally, you can try running the following commands

> chkdsk X: /R
>
> sfc /scannow

Comment: So I run Dependency Walker on both the WinServer08 and Win7, the server is missing quite a few dll, including mf.dll, mfplat.dll, wlanpi.dll, etc. Is it good to transfer those from my Win7 to the server? If not, how can I fix this?

Comment: Added some more info - sfc /scannow is likely to be the one that fixes things up.

Comment: sfc /scannow: "Windows Resource Protection didn't find any integrity violations". Then I transfered the Win7 dlls into the server and then sfc /scanfile=...: "Windows Resource Protection cannot perform the requested operation". Ran chkdsk still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error and it was due to 32 bit version of Apache24 software from apache lounge was run on 64-bit windows 7. I uninstalled the 32 bit version and installed a new 64-bit version of the same.

That resolved this issue. Can be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for me
Install "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 x86"

error solve for me
and Apache  server start successfully

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to install earlier version of Xampp:  5.6.31 ( I found the advice on internet) - tried before reinstal Microsoft Visual 2015, Updates , - I have Win 8.1 . Worked from the start.

Answer (score -1):

1. There are many reasons which stops Apache or any other program to run or sometimes the program didn't able to find suitable software for its execution. In windows OS this problem is due to busy port or due vc14,vc15 i.e. Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable package depending on your software.
2. Here we discuss only the second case i.e. Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable package. Now you have to check which one package your software needs whether it is 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015 or 2017. If you have all other versions except the needed one you can't start your software. Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable package 2015 version helped me to resolve my problem.
3. Like in Apache http server website it is mentioned
   [apache recommnds vc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWy5l.png)